# How to Split Buffered Observable stream into 3 Observables and move items between the 3 Observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

First of all I'm not very familiar with Observables so I have to ask you guys to create clarity in my head. I'm working on a web-app which has an Angular client and a Rails server.
For every request which goes from the client to the server I would like to create a Task and add it to a Task listing. This is my ServerTask class:

```
export class ServerTask {

  private _state$ = new BehaviorSubject<ServerTaskState>({type:"pending"});
  readonly state$ = this._state$.asObservable();
  readonly createdAt: number;
  readonly id: string;

  constructor(readonly description: string) {
    this.id = generateUUIDv4();
    this.createdAt = Date.now();
  }

  get state() {
    return this._state$.value;
  }

  public succeeded() {
    this._state$.next({type: "success"});
    this._state$.complete();
  }

  public failed(message: string) {
    this._state$.next({type: "failure", message});
    this._state$.complete();
  }
}
```

So in my servertask.service.ts there is a Subject which takes all the created Tasks:

```
private readonly _newTaskEvent$ = new Subject<ServerTask>();
```

To buffer a fix amount of Tasks I use scan:

```
  private readonly _internalTasks$ : Observable<ServerTask[]>= this._newTaskEvent$.pipe(
    scan((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur].slice(-10), []),
    startWith([]),
    debounceTime(0),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

From there I would like to get a List of all Tasks which have for example the state$ "pending".
So I created a function to Filter the tasks by state:

```
private getTasks(state: ServerTaskStateType,cmap:(value:ServerTask)=>any): Observable<PublicServerTask[]> {
    return this._internalTasks$.pipe(
      mergeMap(async (tasks)=> {
        return tasks
        .filter(async (t) => {
          const promise = t.state$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
          const resolved = await promise;
          return resolved.type ===  state;})
        .map(cmap)}),
    )
  }
```

and this is how i try to use it:

```
  readonly pendingTasks$: Observable<PendingServerTask[]>  = this.getTasks("pending",(t)=>(
    {description: t.description,}
  ));
  readonly succeededTasks$: Observable<SucceededServerTask[]> = this.getTasks("success",(t)=>(
    {description: t.description,}
  ));

  readonly failedTasks$: Observable<FailedServerTask[]> = this.getTasks("failure",(t)=>(
    {description: t.description,message:t.state.message}
  ));
```

When one task T1 is created and emitted to newTaskEvent$, `pendingTasks$.pipe(first()).toPromise()` contains T1.
Then the t1.succeeded() function is called and afterwards `succeededTasks$.pipe(first()).toPromise()` contains T1 as well. So everything is right!
The problem is that `pendingTasks$.pipe(first()).toPromise()` still contains t1 which now should only be accessable in succeededTasks$.

I have no idea how to solve that problem or if it is possible with that structure in my service.
Thank you guys for any help!

EDIT:

Here is a test how the Pipeline should behave:

```
function firstPromise<T>(obs: Observable<T>) {
  return obs.pipe(first()).toPromise();
}

it("Single pending task later succeeds", async () => {
  const t = instantiate();
  // Create and add Task to _newTaskEvent$
  const task = mkTaskPending("t1");
  t.service.addTask(task);
  // Pending first
  const pending = await firstPromise(t.service.pendingTasks$);
  expect(pending.map((t) => t.description)).toEqual(["t1"]);
  const succeeded = await firstPromise(t.service.succeededTasks$);
  expect(succeeded.map((t) => t.description)).toEqual([]);
  // Changed to succeed
  task.succeeded();
  // Now succeeded !!--Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete--!!
  const succeededLater = await firstPromise(t.service.succeededTasks$);
  expect(succeededLater.map((t) => t.description)).toEqual(["t1"]);
  // Nothing remains pending
  const pendingLater = await firstPromise(t.service.pendingTasks$);
  expect(pendingLater.map((t) => t.description)).toEqual([]);
});
```

Comment: i would very much advise not mixing async / await / promises and observables

Answer (score 0):

this issue seems to be occurring because you only look at the first observation of a given tasks state until a new task is added to internal, at which point you look again.

I think you need to rewrite your `getTasks` function like so:

```
private getTasks(state: ServerTaskStateType,cmap:(value:ServerTask)=>any): Observable<PublicServerTask[]> {
    return this._internalTasks$.pipe(
      switchMap(tasks =>  // switchMap to cancel last subscription on new tasks
        // combine all task state observables, inner map into state and task
        combineLatest(tasks.map(t => t.state$.pipe(map(ts => [ts, t])))).pipe(
          // filter on task state and map into task / use map function
          map(taskStates => taskStates.filter(([ts, t]) => ts.type === state).map(([ts, t]) => cmap(t)))
        )
      )
    )
}
```

one thing to understand here, this will cause all streams to emit whenever a task is added or it's state is changed, even if there are no changes in that particular task stream.

Comment: Thank you for that advise! i needed some time to do research on how the combineLatest will act with arrays of observables, but it seems to pick the most recent element from each stream, but don't combine them together. So thats the behaviour I was looking for. Btw I had to edit a little bit ind the filter function like so: `ts instanceof ServerTask? ts.state.type == state :  ts.type === state`. But now when I try to run a test (Added above to my question) I get: **Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 500ms** from Jasmine. Any idea why?

Comment: For your tests, stop using promises and async / await if you’re testing an observable. This is a really bad habit to be in if you’re working with RxJS and it’s going to make your life miserable